# How retrieve some data from SQL Server database while using PostgreSQL database in Laravel

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, laravel

I am working on a project based on Laravel and Postgres.
now i want to retrieve students data where is stored in another server that uses SQL server database. 
i use a search form where i enter the specific student's ID which is stored in SQL server database and i want to fill my form with the data retrieved from SQL server based on the Entered ID and store it in my main database (Postgres).
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have SQL server installed and running setup for PHP environment as suggested by @z2z.

You can go to the `root folder/config/database.php` and insert the credentials of the database for example for `sqlsrv` you can have something like this:

```
 'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

and for `postgre` you can make another one something like this:

```
'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],
```

**Note:** Here the credentials are coming from env file you can have it your own.

Now once the setup is done you can define the connection type in models now for example in user model you need to add inside the class:

```
protected $connection ="sqlsrv";
```

to get the users from `sql` database or you can define:

```
protected $connection ="pgsql";
```

to get users from `postgre` database

or you can call a raw query something like this:

```
$users = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select(...);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Postgres also has a feature called postgres_fdw which can allow you to "connect" your sql database to your postgres DB and query it as if it's in the same database. In some cases this can work well, in other cases it's slow.
docs here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html

Comment: @JoeLove Great. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing its MS SQL Server 20XX. Things to do..

- On the server, install SQL Server Driver for PHP including all the pre-requisites listed on the download page.
  Configure PHP to use the appropriate SQLSRV driver in php.ini. 
  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1258.accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx#Using_the_SQLSRV_Driver
- In laravel, Setup Config & Model as suggested by @Nitish Kumar